# Order of the zero z=0 of $f(z)=\frac{z^{3}}{1+z -e^{z}}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I found this exercise: Found the order of the zero $z=0$ of

$$f(z)=\frac{z^{3}}{1+z -e^{z}}$$

Using the series expansion of $e^z$ I have
$$f(z)=\frac{z^{3}}{1+z - \{ 1+z+z^2/2! + z^3/3! +...\}}$$
$$f(z)=\frac{z^{3}}{-z^2/2! - z^3/3! -...}$$

I'm stuck in the conclusion, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just cancel $z^2$ to get
$$
\frac{-2z^{\color{#C00000}{1}}}{1+\frac13z+\frac1{12}z^3+\cdots}
$$
Thus, the order of the zero at $z=0$ is $\color{#C00000}{1}$.